# How to change SwiftUI Picker view size with no additional space?

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying to implement Piker view from SwftUI.

I have simple Picker with a few elements in it to display. I set a frame with to 50 only, added border to it and applied view modifier .clipped(). Heres code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("")) {
                Text("1").tag(1)
                Text("2").tag(2)
                Text("3").tag(3)
            }
            //.clipped()
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: 50)
            .clipped()
        }
        .border(Color.red)
   }
}
```

Everything looks ok. But, the problem start to occur when run the app and at the moment of running just open **Debug View Hierarchy** and you'll see like the actual size if **Picker width is much bigger** and I don't know why is that happening. Please, if you know how to fix it, I'll appearance it a lot, thank you

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497649/how-do-i-make-this-picker-clip-properly? Actually why it is a problem for you, it is internal representation?

Comment: thanks but it didn't work with iOS 14 and Xcode 12.3. This is the problem to me because when I combine it with other UI elements then it will block the interaction with other UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with content shape, it should restrict picker hit testing only to clipped area, like

```
VStack { 
    Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("")) { 
          Text("1").tag(1) 
          Text("2").tag(2) 
          Text("3").tag(3) 
     } //.clipped() 
     .labelsHidden()
     .frame(width: 50) 
     .clipped()
     .contentShape(Rectangle())   // << here !!
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works like a charm) I actually did't know that in SwiftUI we can define interacting area of the view, pretty cool 